# facelets totally escape xml

Tags: jsf, facelets

always i use el expressions like this;

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}" escape="true" />;
```

and i cannot escape from xml in input fields:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" />
```

is there a way to totally escape xml in facelets.

for instance a context parameter;

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.ESCAPE_XML</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: How do you mean "totally escape xml"? I'm not sure what it is you want to do. BTW, escape="true" is the default for h:outputText.

Answer (score 0):

Override the **renderer** for `<h:outputText>` and comment out the part where it escapes the text. Then register your renderer in your `faces.config.xml`.

Of course, this will only work if you use that tag. It won't work if you just output an expression eg `#{bean.value}`.

Personally, I'd rather stick with having to add the escape attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried it but you could maybe use a custom converter like the one bellow(Converts `\n` to `<br/>`)

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class BreakLineConverter implements Converter {

    /**
     * No conversion required 
     */
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Converts All \r  \n  \r\n  into break
     */
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {      
        if (null==value || StringUtils.isEmpty((String)value))
            return "";      
        String val=value.toString();
        //This will take care of Windows and *nix based line separators
        return val.replaceAll("\r\n", "<br />").replaceAll("\r", "<br />").replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
    }

}
```

Register converter in faces-config.xml

```
<converter>
    <description>Converts data to be displayed in web format
    </description>
     <converter-id>BreakLineConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>comp.web.converter.BreakLineConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the `h:outputText` and `h:inputText` by default **already** escapes XML entities. You can't even turn it off in `h:inputText` as you could do in `h:outputText`. Your problem lies somewhere else. Maybe your understanding/definition of "escape XML" is wrong. Also, your `<context-param>` example suggests that you want to *disable* XML escaping. You can't do that for `h:inputText` because your webapp would then be prone for [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html). You don't want to have that.